# Swing keeps spawning thread on invokeLater()

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to Java UI and Swing and I can't understand why is this happening.

```
public class ZAsciiMapWindow extends JFrame implements KeyListener, Runnable {

    ...

    // SWING STUFF
    private JTextArea displayArea = null;
    private JTextField typingArea = null;

    public ZAsciiMapWindow(final ZMap map, final ZHuman player) {
        super("ZAsciiMapWindow");
        this.map = map;
        this.player = player;
    }

    ...

    public void show() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);

        //Schedule a job for event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this);
    }

    private void addComponentsToPane() {

        this.typingArea = new JTextField(20);
        this.typingArea.addKeyListener(this);
        this.typingArea.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

        this.displayArea = new JTextArea();
        this.displayArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.displayArea);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(375, 125));

        getContentPane().add(this.typingArea, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Set up the content pane.
        this.addComponentsToPane();

        //Display the window.
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }
}
```

Then when I call `new ZAsciiMapWindow(x, y).show()` from my `main()`, it just never shows the JFrame. And if I debug I find out it keeps calling `createAndShowGUI()` to the infinite.

Why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this);` calls the run method of the passed Runnable. Your `run` method is `createAndShowGUI();`, which calls `this.setVisible(true);` which I assume calls `this.show()` which then calls `javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this);`.

So the behaviour is not very surprising.

I would start by avoiding having a class extend JFrame, implement KeyListener and Runnable.

For example, it is good practice to have a JFrame inside your class instead of extending JFrame directly.

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't know there was a `JFrame.show()`... I didn't pretend to override. And about extending JFrame I was just following an example from Sun... I mean Oracle.